# regex: get string in url login/test

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url

```
https://test.com/login/param2
```

how do I get the the second parameter "param2" from the url using REGEX?

the url can also be

```
https://test.com/login/param2/
```

So the regex should work for both urls.

I tried

```
  var loc = window.location.href;
  var locParts = loc.split('/');
```

and then looping through locParts, but that seems inefficient.

The "param2" can be have number, alphatical character from a-z, and a dash.

Comment: It's only those two possibilities?

Comment: use locParts[last-Inddex]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex [`/[^\/]+(?=\/?$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/yU92NZ/1).

```js
var a = 'https://test.com/login/facebook',
  b = 'https://test.com/login/facebook/';


var reg = /[^\/]+(?=\/?$)/;
console.log(
  a.match(reg)[0],
  b.match(reg)[0]
)
```

---

Or using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) get last non-empty element.

```js
var a = 'https://test.com/login/facebook',
  b = 'https://test.com/login/facebook/';

var splita = a.split('/'),
  splitb = b.split('/');

console.log(
  splita.pop() || splita.pop(),
  splitb.pop() || splitb.pop()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions might be compact, but they're certainly not automatically efficient if you can do what you want without.

Here's how you can change your code:

```js
var loc = 'https://test.com/login/facebook/'; // window.location.href;
var locParts = loc.split('/').filter(function(str) {return !!str});
var faceBookText = locParts.pop();
console.log(faceBookText);
```

The filter removes the last empty item you would get if the url ends with '/'. That's all you need, then just take the last item.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using JS only (so no regex), you can use this :

```
var lastParameter = window.location.href.split('/').slice(-1);
```

Basicaly, like you, I fetch the URL, split by the `/` character, but then I use the [`splice` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice) to get teh last element of the `split` result array.